# How to parse column (with list data) within a DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

There is a column in a DataFrame that contains a list and I want to parse that list for the first element and replace that column with it. So for example:

```
col1
[elem1, elem2]
[elem3, elem4]
```

I want to make this:

```
col1
elem1
elem3
```

I've tried `dataFrameName.withColumn("col1", explode($"col1"))` but it gives me a NoSuchElementException. What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

To replace the ArrayType column `col1` with its first element, `explode` would not be useful.  You can simply replace it with `$"col1"(0)` (or `$"col1".getItem(0)`), as shown below:

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq(
  Seq("elem1", "elem2"),
  Seq("elem3", "elem4")
).toDF("col1")

df.withColumn("col1", $"col1"(0)).show
// +-----+
// | col1|
// +-----+
// |elem1|
// |elem3|
// +-----+
```

Note that you may have a separate issue with the encountered `NoSuchElementException`, as `explode`-ing an ArrayType column normally wouldn't generate such an exception.